# Regex for European name

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a Regex for European name.
I found this one, works good with javascript:

```
/^([ \u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-])+$/
```

I convert it for PHP, but it doesn't work:

```
/^([ \x{00C0}-\x{01FF}a-zA-Z'\-])+$/
```

My regex must match with name like that:

> Jean-Paul le Marchant
>
> Jérôme L'activé

So characters a-zA-Z, no special chars like @#$%^© etc. but all accented/european characters like éèàôç etc.

Comment: I suppose you also need `'` even though it is a "special character"?

Comment: Why would you do this? Maybe you can prevent someone from entering 'J0hn', but they still can enter a name like 'oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'. You're never going to stop malicious input with a regex check. And since you apparently support unicode already, don't worry about anything anyone enters. Maybe someone *is* called 'John Doe the 3rd' or 也许明年. Why block it? (Sorry if I've offended any Chinese people.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to activate Unicode mode for these escape sequences to work:

```
/^([ \x{00C0}-\x{01FF}a-zA-Z'\-])+$/u
```

Note that the parentheses are not necessary:

```
/^[ \x{00C0}-\x{01FF}a-zA-Z'\-]+$/u
```

A character class gives a single "element" of your regex that can be repeate with a quantifier immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use utf8 encoding and then slap the `u` modifier on the regex:

```
$regex = '/^([ \x{00C0}-\x{01FF}a-zA-Z\'\-])+$/u';
```

Answer (score 0):

This PHP regex should work:

```
$str = "Jérôme L'activé";
if (preg_match("/^[\s\x{00C0}-\x{01FF}a-z'-]+$/iu", $str, $match))
   print_r($match);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Jérôme L'activé
)
```

**RegEx Flags**

- u - Enable Unicode in matching
- i - Ignore Case Comparison

**PS:** Inside square brackets you don't need to escape hyphen `-` if it is at first or last place.

Comment: @m.buettner: Thanks, That is right and I corrected my note.